# Difference between encodeBase64URLSafeString and encodeBase64URLSafe

Tags: apache-commons

I was wondering what the actual difference is between the following two functions :
encodeBase64URLSafeString 
encodeBase64URLSafe

The apache documentation says the difference is that encodeBase64URLSafe does not chunk the output while encodeBase64URLSafeString does ! but what does that mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Chunking is just adding a new-line after every ~74 characters (so it's acceptable for email)

Comment: do you have a reference for that?

Answer (score -1):

The return type differs:

```
public static byte[]  [More ...] encodeBase64URLSafe(byte[] binaryData) {
    return encodeBase64(binaryData, false, true);
}

public static String  [More ...] encodeBase64URLSafeString(byte[] binaryData) {
    return StringUtils.newStringUtf8(encodeBase64(binaryData, false, true));
}
```

Did you mean what is the difference between chunked and non-chunked, your question is not very clear...